# Where am I going wrong with this imaginary slope problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

The equation of the line through $2 + 3i$ and $0$ can be written as
$az + b \overline{z} = 0$for some complex numbers $a$ and $b$. Find the quotient $b/a$ in rectangular form.

I got a = -2+3i and b = 2+3i. For some reason this is wrong.

I used the same process as [slope in imaginary plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932629/slope-in-imaginary-plane/2932643?noredirect=1#comment6058734_2932643), but I am getting the result as b = 0. This would mean both b and a are equal to 0. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `Where did I go wrong?` Show your steps, otherwise it's impossible to guess.

Comment: a(2+3i)+b(2-3i) = a(0) + b(0) -> 2a+3a*i + 2b-3b*i -> a = \frac{(-2+3*i)b}{2+3i}. Plug that back in and you get 4b = 0. So, b = 0. Plug that back in and you get     a = 0 too! That seems wrong.

Comment: Where did you plug back this $a = \frac{(-2+3*i)b}{2+3i}$ ?

Comment: back into  a(2+3i)+b(2-3i)

Comment: @ilikepi314 `back into` That should only give you $0=0$ since that's where you derived the equality from. And, quite obviously, you can't solve one equation for *two* unknowns $\,a,b\,$. But you don't need to, since $\,az+b\bar z=0\,$ is homogeneous in $\,a,b\,$, so you are free to pick $\,b=1\,$, or $\,b=2+3i\,$, or whatever $\,b \ne 0\,$ you want, then calculate $\,a\,$ and you are done.

Comment: @dxiv wouldn't they be different results for a?

Comment: @ilikepi314 Yes, they would be different, since $a,b$ are not uniquely determined. Note that $a\cdot z+b \cdot \bar z=0$ and $wa \cdot z + wb \cdot \bar z=0$ represent the same equation for all $w \ne 0$.

Comment: @dxiv I got (-2+3i)/(2+3i) is this correct

Comment: @ilikepi314 No, that's $\,a/b\,$. It's also not normalized to cartesian form.

Comment: Is cartesian rectangular?

Comment: nevermind I got it sorry about that

Comment: @dxiv I checked my results and it is still wrong

Comment: @ilikepi314 Post your results (into the question, *not* as comments), otherwise no one can guess what's wrong.

Comment: @ilikepi314 `For some reason this is wrong` What makes you think it's wrong? It's not.

Comment: I checked with my teacher. He still says it's wrong

Comment: @ilikepi314 Why don't you check for yourself. The equation represents a line (*why?*), and both the origin $0$ and $2+3i$ satisfy it. But, as I wrote in a previous comment, the solution is not unique, unless there were additional conditions imposed which you haven't posted.

Comment: thats all i am given

Comment: @ilikepi314 Then, again, [check for yourself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933283/where-am-i-going-wrong-with-this-imaginary-slope-problem?noredirect=1#comment6062706_2933283) and support or otherwise clarify the `For some reason this is wrong` part of the question.

Comment: I didn't simplify it into simplest terms. :((((((((((