# Solving $\alpha z + \beta \bar z + \gamma = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I attempted to find a general solution for the presented equation : $$\alpha z +\beta \bar z + \gamma =0$$
with $z,\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb C$, my demonstration goes as below:$$\alpha z + \beta \bar z + \gamma = 0$$$$\implies (\alpha-\beta ) z+\beta (\bar z +z) + \gamma = 0$$Since $\forall z \in \mathbb C, z+\bar z = 2\operatorname{Re}(z)$ with $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ denoting the real part of the complex number $z$. then as we proceed :$$(\alpha-\beta)z+2\beta\operatorname{Re}(z) + \gamma =0$$$$\implies 2\beta\operatorname{Re}(z)=(\beta-\alpha)z-\gamma$$
we restart from the initial equation to extract :$$\alpha z + \beta (\bar z - z)+ \beta z + \gamma = 0$$
$$\implies (\alpha+\beta)z -2\beta \operatorname{Im}(z) + \gamma = 0$$ Since $\forall z\in \mathbb C,z-\bar z = 2\operatorname{Im}(z)$ with $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ denoting the imaginary part of the complex number $z$. then we proceed :$$2\beta\operatorname{Im}(z) = (\alpha + \beta)z+ \gamma.$$So far we found both the real part and the imaginary part in function of $z$ itself which is more than enough to find the value of $z$.$$\begin{cases}2\beta \operatorname{Re}(z)=(\beta-\alpha)z-\gamma\\2\beta\operatorname{Im}(z)=(\alpha+\beta)z+\gamma\end{cases}$$ and it is quite obvious that for $\forall z \in \mathbb C,z=\operatorname{Re}(z)+i\operatorname{Im}(z)$
$$\implies (\beta-\alpha)z-\gamma + i(\alpha+\beta)z+i\gamma = 2\beta z$$$$\implies z(\beta-\alpha-2\beta+i(\alpha +\beta))=\gamma(1-i)$$$$\implies z(i(\alpha+\beta)-(\alpha+\beta))=\gamma(1-i)$$$$\implies z(\alpha+\beta)(i-1)=\gamma(1-i)$$$$\implies z(\alpha+\beta)=-\gamma$$$$\implies z=\frac{-\gamma}{\alpha+\beta}$$ Which is clearly Wrong since this is the exact solution of a different equation with different parameters.$z=\frac{-\gamma}{\alpha+\beta}$ solves $(\alpha + \beta)z+\gamma=0$. The given solution stands only for real numbers since $\forall x \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C, \bar x = x$.Trying with $\alpha= 3+2i, \beta=1+i, \gamma=5+3i$, the previous solution yields $z=-\frac{29}{25}+\frac{3}{25}i$ then $\bar z = -\frac{29}{25}-\frac{3}{25}i$.Multiplying each one with the corresponding coefficients yields $\alpha z=-\frac{93}{25}-\frac{49}{25}i$ and $\beta \bar z=-\frac{46}{25}-\frac{104}{25}i$ which is clearly $\alpha z+ \beta \bar z \neq -5-3i$ the desired $\gamma$. Please tell me if I had a calculation error, or even a systematic error in my deduction procedure

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374659/42969.

Comment: Your first conclusion $(\alpha-\beta ) z+\beta (\bar z +z) + \gamma - \alpha \bar z = 0$ looks already wrong. Then the term $\alpha \bar z$ gets lost in the next step.

Comment: It is wrong that $z-\bar z = 2\operatorname{Im}(z)$. It should be $z-\bar z = 2\operatorname{Im}(z)\ \color{red}i$.

Comment: Yes and I figured out lately and I was really depressed