# Origin shift in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, coordinate-systems

I'm just learning about basic complex geometry, and we were taught the locus for a complex line that passes through the origin, arg(z) = θ. But this form of a complex line is cleaner than the others, so I thought of generalizing this same equation for a line that DOESN'T pass through the origin. How can such an equation be derived using an origin shift in the Argand plane, to a fixed complex number z' = Re(z'), analogous to the Cartesian Plane, where the X intercept is non zero? Any other generalization way would be helpful too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\,\arg(z)=\theta\,$ is the equation of a ray (half-line) through the origin. The translation in the complex plane that maps point $\,z_0\,$ to the origin is $\,z \mapsto z-z_0\,$, so the equation of a ray through $\,z_0\,$ is $\,\arg(z-z_0)=\theta\,$. See also [When does $az + b\bar{z} + c = 0$ represent a line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374659/when-does-az-b-barz-c-0-represent-a-line) for other ways to write the equation of a line.

Comment: @dxiv cool, thanks.